# How to assert enum in C# using NUnit

Tags: c#, debugging, testing, nunit

I'm using NUnit on a .NET C# project

I need to assert that historyRecord.InstrType is equal to InstrType.Nanodac

I've got a variable `myVal` of type `InstrType`

where InstrType is an enum:

```
public enum InstrType
{
HydraSbs,
HydraLbs,
HydraSfs,
HydraLfs,
HydraEconomique,
Blind,
Lxio,
Sxio,
Sfse,
T800QVga,
T800SVGa,
Eycon10,
Eycon20,
T2550,
T2750,
Nanodac
}
```

I need to assert this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(myVal, InstrType.Nanodac)
```

but it raises an exception ("expected Nanodac but was HydraSbs").
So I tried this:

```
Assert.That(myVal, Is.EqualTo(InstrType.Nanodac))
```

again, it raises the same exception!

I tested with the debugger and `myVal` is valorized correctly as InstrType.Nanodac

I smell an enum bad cast as it picks the first value of the list (hydraSbs)

Comment: How can it be a bad cast if they're the same type? Anyway, you need to supply a bit more information on **how** `myVal` is set, and from what. Show a little bit more code because from what your question tells, this is frankly implausible.

Comment: casting implicitly when passing the value to the AreEqual() or EqualTo() functions. These functions know nothing about my custom type InstrType.

Comment: In that case it should pass, because it'd cast **both** values to InstrType.HydraSbs, incorrectly.

Comment: How is the value assigned to `myVal`?

Comment: using a switch case which sets the value myVal = InstrType.Nanodac; very simple

Comment: ...and you have verified that that code line is hit when running your test?

Comment: of course, and it get sets to nanodac

Comment: I agree, we need to see how `myVal` is set.  It sounds like it is never being set explicitly which means it is defaulting to the first value in the enum, `HydraSbs`.

Comment: Can you confirm: If you set a breakpoint on the Assert, can you confirm that `myVar` has the value `InstrType.Nanodac`?

Comment: yes, i can confirm that. I set a breakpoint just before calling the assert line

Comment: got it. I need to clean and rebuild the project in order to make it work. Maybe it was the common "old-lib-in-there" problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to clean and rebuild the project in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

First off your original assert should work fine, even if the arguments are technically the wrong way round.

My guess is that the value wasn't actually getting set correctly.
So the assert is throwing the correct error message in that case.

Example code:
TestMethod1 shows the assert working correctly.
TestMethod2 is an example of the value not actually being set somewhere along the line.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    public enum InstrType
    {
        HydraSbs,           // = 0
        HydraLbs,           // = 1
        HydraSfs,           // = 2
        HydraLfs,           // = 3
        HydraEconomique,    // = 4
        Blind,              // = 5
        Lxio,               // = 6
        Sxio,               // = 7
        Sfse,               // = 8
        T800QVga,           // = 9
        T800SVGa,           // = 10
        Eycon10,            // = 11
        Eycon20,            // = 12
        T2550,              // = 13
        T2750,              // = 14
        Nanodac             // = 15
    }

    public class HistoryRecord
    {
        public InstrType InstructionType { get; set; }

        public HistoryRecord(InstrType instructionType)
        {
            //NOTE: Possible bug here
            //We could possibly be missing this assignment perhaps:
            //InstructionType = instructionType;
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This method should pass
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var myVal = InstrType.Nanodac;
            Assert.AreEqual(InstrType.Nanodac, myVal);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method should fail with -> Expected:<Nanodac>. Actual:<HydraSbs>
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            // Please check the 'HistoryRecord' class above for the possible error
            // Here the the value of InstructionType has not actually been set yet, so will default to 0 in the underlying datatype (int)
            // In this case that underlying 0 value will be mapped to the first enum value which is HydraSbs
            // that is why you'd get the error -> Expected:<Nanodac>. Actual:<HydraSbs>
            var historyRecord = new HistoryRecord(InstrType.Nanodac);
            var myVal = historyRecord.InstructionType;

            var intValue = (int)myVal;
            Assert.AreEqual(0, intValue);

            Assert.AreEqual(InstrType.Nanodac, myVal); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is just a suggestion, I would cast both to an *int* and then compare.

**Here is an Example**

```
Assert.AreEqual((int)myVal, (int)InstrType.Nanodac)
```

or you could move the expected result to the left side, avoiding the cast.

```
Assert.AreEqual(InstrType.Nanodac, myVal)
```

p.s. Glad a clean/rebuild worked.